# django admin: apply filter_horizontal to an inline model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

If according to django documentation, filter_horizontal is one of the shared features for the InlineModelAdmin class... Then I just need to understand syntactically how to apply it to an inline model.

So I have an inline for a model called `Keyword`. I would like it to display using the filter_horizontal feature on the admin page for changing the `Statement` model.

I was hoping it would be as simple as

```
class KeywordInline(admin.TabularInline):
     model = Keyword.statement.through

class KeywordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [KeywordInline,]
    filter_horizontal = ('keyword',)

class StatementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('statement_id', 'title', 'author', 'released_by', 'issue_date', 'access', 'full_text',)
    list_filter = (StatementListFilter, 'released_by', 'issue_date', 'access',)
    search_fields = ('statement_id', 'title', 'author', 'issue_date',)
    inlines = [ KeywordInline,]
```

But this has... literally no effect on the display of the inline. What am I missing (syntactically)?

Comment: Trying     `class KeywordInline(admin.TabularInline):`
         `model = Keyword.statement.through`
         `filter_horizontal = ('keyword',)`

gives me an error when I run `python manage.py makemigrations` of `<class 'gtr_site.admin.KeywordInline'>: (admin.E020) The value of 'filter_horizontal[0]' must be a many-to-many field.` So I switched to the `Keyword` model's m2m field, which is just called statements. That got me `The value of 'filter_horizontal[0]' refers to 'statements', which is not an attribute of 'gtr_site.Keyword_statement'.`

Comment: So I need to somehow get an attrbute of Keyword_statement. But... What exactly is Keyword_statement? And how can I figure out its attributes?

Comment: Did you figure this one out?